# photoshop: how can i focus one person with gradient

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I want to make a photo that has a transparent blue background(under that transparent blue is another photo ) and one person is focused.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify - either a background is transparent or it's blue. The sample above has a figure in focus on a blurred background. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. Please share what you have tried and where you are having difficulty. Users here are very happy to help, but this isn't a "tutorial on demand" site. You should at least show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i want it to look like that photo. @JeffK

Comment: I tried to make it but I do not know how to focus on one person. This is what I managed to make so far https://www.facebook.com/rkmaglajmaglaj/photos/3261705677393893 @Scott

Comment: I still have no clue what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then the figure you want in focus is on a separate layer.
What I'm assuming you want is a background image that's blurred, a foreground image in focus, and a gradient layer. That's essentially 3 layers:

[image]

Beyond that you can change your gradient, add text, or make any changes to come to your final result. I hope this answers your question....